# View a File Encrypted by the Encrypt Class of Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I used the encryption class of codeigniter to encrypt the uploaded files in my server. Then I will just decrypt it whenever I wan't to access it like this:

```
$decrypted = $this->encrypt->decode($fileContents);
```

My problem right now is that I don't know what to do with my variable $decrypted, I want to view my file but as far as i have googled so far, functions for viewing file takes a parameter which is a url, but then I don't want to save the decrypted file in the server for the sake of viewing it. I need help.

Comment: Spit it out to the browser with the correct `Content-type: */*` header. If the person has a plugin to view it in the browser, the file will be presented. Otherwise, the person can download it.

Comment: can you show me on how to spit it out to the browser? @Ismael Miguel?

Comment: I've never used code igniter, but, if the variable `$decripted` contains the file contents, using a `echo` will work.

Comment: i tried echoing my $decrypted variable. it gave me a string, a very long string that i cannot understand. like this 'sdfsdFSD#$@424324SDASDa#$@@4@$234SDFsdf.........'

Comment: Where do you have the encrypted code?

Comment: Have you given the encryption key in config file?

Comment: yes @John, I have it in my config file.

Comment: @Ismael Miguel do you mean the encryption code of the file or the encrypted file?

Comment: I mean, do you store it in a file or in a database? If it is a database, is your file and connection encoding the same as your database's encoding? If you are writting the encrypted content into a file, is your server Windows?

Comment: I'm writting the encrypted content into a file and yes my server is windows.

Comment: Are you using `fopen` to read the file? If so, change the more from, for example, `'r'` to `'rb'` and the problem is solved. Otherwise, change your code to use `fopen` and use the refered mode. Make the same change to the function to write the file.

Comment: I'm using file_get_contents then after that i decrypt the returned value. if i'm going to use fopen i need to save the decypted file to the server right?

Comment: Use `fopen` for both. To read and write the file. The mode `w+b` is to over-write and `rb` is to read. If you need help, check here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php You probably have some `\r` or `\n` chars on the file you create. Windows silently translates those into `\r\n`, which causes problems. Appending `b` to the mode will force 'binary mode', which won't make that translation. (There is also the oposite, the `t` mode, which forces the translation of those line ending codes). All the needed information is in that link. If you need more help, just comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ismael Miguel was right. I just need to spit it out to the browser with the correct Content-type: */* header. like this:

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
echo $decrypted;
```

I understand that the file will just appear if the person has a plugin to view it in the browser. I think there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem with the codeIgniter encrypt class or just file viewing problem? I mean, are you getting the file decoded?

Just Check these if you have given the encryption key in config file. ie.,

```
    $config['encryption_key'] = 'some_key';
```

1.Have you loaded the codeIgniter class ?

```
    $this->load->library('encrypt');
```

2.If your file to be encoded is a view page, have you got the contents of the file right?

```
    $fileContents = $this->load->view('file_name','',TRUE);
```

3.encode the file

```
    $encrypted_string = $this->encrypt->encode($fileContents);
```

4.decode the file

```
    $plaintext_string = $this->encrypt->decode($encrypted_string);
```

After the third step you will get a long jumbled string which is the encrypted string.
after the fourth step you will get back the file contents back.

You can echo the results on each steps to verify.

Hopes this gives you an idea of codeIgniter encryption class.

Comment: i have done those steps from 1 to 4, my only problem is that i don't know how to view my file with the plain text string that i have after decoding the encrypted file...

Comment: what you get when echoing $plaintext_string?

Comment: a very long string that i cannot understand. like this 'sdfsdFSD#$@424324SDASDa#$@@4@$234SDFsdfdsfsdfsweqw21314we231aedwerqw214234e@!#$$%@$!#dSSvdwae@#$!@#$F'

Comment: is it same when you echo $fileContents? You must give more code if you wish us to help you.

Comment: it's not the same. :(